# substitute 2 substrings from a single line in a file into 2 different lines in a different file from command line

Tags: bash, sed, command-line, grep, cut

I have a text file with however many lines. One line is:

```
fixed_stringA = 123, fixed_stringB = 456
```

I have a second text file (again with however many lines). These 2 lines are in this order, in middle of the file:

```
found_value1=unknown1  
found_value2=unknown2
```

My goal is to modify these two lines second text file so that the it will now read:

```
found_value1=123  
found_value2=456
```

My goal is to do this on the command line without calling another script. The following code works, but I wonder if it can be shortened or improved:

```
value_variable=$(grep "fixed_stringA = [0-9]*, fixed_stringB = [0-9]*" first_file \
| sed -E 's/fixed_stringA = ([0-9]+), fixed_stringB = ([0-9]+)/\1,\2/'); \
value1=$(echo $value_variable | cut -d "," -f 1); \ 
value2=$(echo $value_variable | cut -d "," -f 2); \
sed -i -E "s/unknown1/$value1/" second_file.txt; \
sed -i -E "s/unknown2/$value2/" second_file.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can get it down to these two lines:

```
values="$(sed -n -E 's/^.*fixed_stringA\s*=\s*([0-9]+)\s*,\s*fixed_stringB\s*=\s*([0-9]+).*$/\1,\2/p' first_file)"
sed -i -E -e "s/unknown1/${values%,*}/" -e "s/unknown2/${values#*,}/" second_file.txt
```

The first line uses sed with the `-n` flag so it suppresses regular output, and it finds the target line, extracts the numeric values into the capture groups `\1` and `\2` and turns them into `123,456` and prints that alone, saving that to the variable `$values`.

The next line does two substitutions in `second_file.txt`: everything before the comma in `$values` for `unknown1` and everything after the comma for `unknown2`.

But I'm sure some awk export will be along any minute with a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, using `grep` along with `sed` is almost always superfluous, because `sed` can filter by itself. In your case, you can use the `p` flag to the `s` command to print on a match only, then `d`elete to suppress normal output:

```
sed -E 's/fixed_stringA = ([0-9]+), fixed_stringB = ([0-9]+)/\1,\2/p;d' first_file
```

Next, you would usually store the replacement strings in the hold space to apply them on the second file, but that will not work with `-i`nsplace editing, so we need a second `sed` command. Let's use the first one to generate that script for the second one:

```
sed -i.bak $(sed -E 's/fixed_stringA = ([0-9]+), fixed_stringB = ([0-9]+)/s_unknown1_\1_;s_unknown2_\2_/p;d' first_file) second_file
```

The inner script will produce the output `s_unknown1_123_;s_unknown2_456_` which is the script needed to the second file.

*Note: I use `-i.bak` to be compatible with other `sed` versions and to keep a copy in case I mess up the source file.*